# this.template.querySelector() vs jQuery$() vs document.getElementById()

Tags: lightning-web-components

Why `this.template.querySelector('input-386');` and `document.getElementById('input-386');` return **null** while `$('#input-386');` returns the correct DOM element ?

Comment: this.template.querySelector('input-386') should also require # sign. not sure about getElementById() though

Comment: I've tried with #, not better. Also tried to query on classes with '.' and without. It still return null.

Comment: Also, that code below doesn't return any elements: `    const errFields = this.template.querySelectorAll("slds-has-error");
    errFields.forEach(field => {
      console.log(field);
      console.log(field.name);
    });`

Comment: it's a bit hacky, but you may want to try using a data attribute to your input, then see if querySelector finds it: 
document.querySelector('[data-foo]');  or specifically by value of data:
document.querySelector('[data-foo=bar]');